# btc-e price quotes throught api

Tags: api, btce

Can anyone give me the API details on how to access the prices quotes shown on home page of BTC-E.com.

the api link on the site does not provide details on how to access bid and ask prices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get any price quotes, in a JSON format, using these kinds of endpoints:

- https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_usd/ticker
- https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker
- https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_btc/ticker

The structure of the endpoint is `https://btc-e.com/api/2` and then `currency_currency` and then `/ticker`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: How about getting the order list, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Here are more options to access data:

https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/depth

https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/trades

Answer (score 1):

The [FAQ page](https://btc-e.com/page/2) at btc-e.com has a FAQ called "API" at the bottom.  If you click it, it opens a list of items which, though BTC-e could change things at any time, so it's a good idea to visit that URL anyway, currently says:

Fee

- BTC/USD - https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/fee
- USD/RUR - https://btc-e.com/api/2/usd_rur/fee

Public API – BTC/USD

- Ticker - https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker
- Trades - https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/trades
- Depth - https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/depth

Public API – LTC/BTC

- Ticker - https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_btc/ticker
- Trades - https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_btc/trades
- Depth - https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_btc/depth

Public API – LTC/USD

- Ticker - https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_usd/ticker
- Trades - https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_usd/trades
- Depth - https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_usd/depth